# windows_exporter service drops connection to prometheus after server reboot

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, grafana, azure-monitoring, prometheus-node-exporter

I am facing a weird issue for windows_exporter service and prometheus connection.
I am using Prometheus grafana to monitor our windows vms (Azure).
Prometheus Grafana server is Linux (Ubuntu) based.

10 critical windows servers are added into Prometheus target history.
Some windows server run 24/7 and some of them are set to auto-shutdown at end of day and restart on next day.

Initial targets when added to prometheus server were working fine but once the servers reboot some of the servers drop connection to prometheus server inconsistently.

Windows VM OS: Windows server 2016 /2019

**Curl from prometheus server to windows target**: curl: (7) Failed to connect to 52.xxx.xxx.xxx port 9182: Connection refused
(Note: connection re-establishes when we restart the service manually in windows servers)

windows_exporter service status when checked on target machine shows running and also set to automatic delayed start , also I get response of metrics for
**http://localhost:9182/metrics**

All linux targets are working perfectly fine no matter how many times we restart them.
Is this issue because of recent windows updates?

Anyone else facing the same issue and have any possible solution for the same?

Thank you for your time!

Prometheus.yml file:

```
 - job_name: 'Win_Server_1'
    scrape_interval: 4m
    static_configs:
            - targets: ['xx.1xx.xx.xx:9182']

  - job_name: 'Win_Server_2'
    scrape_interval: 4m
    static_configs:
            - targets: ['xx.1xx.xx.xx:9182']

  - job_name: 'Win_Server_3'
    scrape_interval: 4m
    static_configs:
            - targets: ['xx.1xx.xx.xx:9182']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a dependency for Winmgmt to the windows_exporter service in addition to the delayed start. This seemed to do the trick for me (5 servers, mix of WS2019 and one WS2022).

```
sc config windows_exporter depend=Winmgmt
```